# change angular mat-checkbox color without ng-deep

Tags: angular, colors, angular-material, frontend

is there a way to have 2 components in angular with two checkboxes which have two seperate colors?

[image]

I want that the checkbox in the table have a different color than the checkbox in the list which is in a different component...I ve already trie with ng-deep but it changes the color for every component..
thanks

Comment: Look up css specivity

Comment: you have 2 components.Both have checkbox and you need different color for those components checkbox. this is your requirement correct?